# orchard cms shape tracer is not selecting my shape

Tags: orchardcms

The shape tracer shows Part_Product [Empty] . I could see the shape renderes, but my shape is not selectable by shape tracer. Any idea?

Regards
George

Comment: You'll have to provide more information than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a silly mistake while I was testing, enclose the data arround html tags, the shape tracer would select the shape